# Javascript remove all occurrence of duplicate element, leaving the only one that is unique

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove elements that occurr more than once and get the unique element. The array always has 3 elements. 
Lets say i have an array [2,3,2], then I need to get 3 which is only unique in the array(removing both 2s, because they occur more than once).

I have tried with following code, but surely it doesnot work as expected.

```
var firstArrTemp = [2,3,2];
var sorted_arr = firstArrTemp.sort();
var unique_element;
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] != sorted_arr[i]) {
        unique_element=sorted_arr[i];
    }
}

alert(unique_element);
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Vohuman, No this is not duplicate, the page you refered gives 2,3 as a resulting array, I just want to get 3, removing both 2s. Please read question carefully before marking as duplicate

Comment: @vohuman: That's not what this question needs. This question asks for a result that contains all elements that are unique.

Comment: @Johan, that is not what i want, please read the post again

Comment: What about when array is [1,2,3] should return [1,2,3]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
    var uniques = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
        if(this.lastIndexOf(this[i]) == this.indexOf(this[i])) {
            uniques.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return uniques;
}

// Usage:

var a = [2, 6, 7856, 24, 6, 24];
alert(JSON.stringify(a.getUnique()));

console.log(a.getUnique()); // [2, 7856]
```

To check if a specific item is unique in the array, it just checks if the first index it's found at, matches the last index it's found at.

Comment: Thats the exact answer. Thanks buddy!

Comment: This is fine for small arrays, but if your array has a large number of elements, this may get pretty slow.

Comment: I completely forgot I had an answer in here. If you know of a faster solution, please answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

One alternative with filter() function:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,2,2,4,3,7,3].sort();
var uniqueValues = myArray.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
  return (item !== arr[i-1] && item !== arr[i+1]);
});
```

Where `uniqueValues` = [1,4,7]

Comment: Sure, this works. However, sorting an array and then iterating over it again seems like double work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I created the perfomance test case completely right (at least I tried), but here are the results: http://jsperf.com/remove-uniques . Not proving anything, but I don't see first sorting then filtering a real problem (or as double work).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers so far all have `O(n log n)` time complexity or worse. This can be done in `O(n)` time though the use of Sets (`Set.has` has `O(1)` complexity) instead of nested loops:

```js
// .sort has complexity O(n log n): it's not needed here, avoid it
const getOnlyUniques = (arr) => {
  const foundOnce = new Set();
  const foundTwice = new Set();
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (foundOnce.has(item)) {
      foundTwice.add(item);
    }
    foundOnce.add(item);
  });
  return arr.filter(item => !foundTwice.has(item));
};
console.log(getOnlyUniques([2, 3, 2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
var a = [2,3,2], result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

    if(getAllIndexes(a, a[i]).length === 1)
        result.push(a[i]);
}

console.log(result);

function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while (~(i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)))
        indexes.push(i);
    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what's going on here o.O Are you iterating over the array twice?

Comment: @Cerbrus Hey, I didn't say it's the best performing solution - just an alternative ;) Though it will be hard to yield < O(N^2) complexity.

Comment: `O(n)` is possible, though use of Sets. (could be done with objects too, but Sets are more appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

```
const nums = [1,2,3,3,3,5,5,5];
const chars = ['a','b','a','b','a','a'];
const mixed = [1,3,'b',3,'b','a','b',3];
const unique = [1,'a',3]; 

const distinct = (arr) => arr.filter((el) => arr.filter((item) => item === el).length === 1);

console.log(distinct(nums)); // [ 1, 2 ]
console.log(distinct(chars)); // []
console.log(distinct(mixed)); // [ 1, 'a' ]
console.log(distinct(unique)); // [ 1, 'a', 3 ]
```

1. first, we'll double loop over "arr" with "filter"

> arr.filter((el) => arr.filter((item) => ... );

2. if "item" is equal to "el" then return its "length"

> arr.filter((el) => arr.filter((item) => item === el).length

- this will return the occurrence count for each element in the array
- let' use the 1st example to illustrate this:
- [1,2,3,3,3,5,5,5] --> [1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3]
- 1 occurred 1 time
- 2 occurred 1 time
- 3 occurred 3 time
- 5 occurred 3 time

3. to return any element that is non-repeating or unique, we just need to specified length to equal "1"

> arr.filter((el) => arr.filter((item) => item === el).length === 1)

- this approach allows you to choose the amount of occurrences from an element you want to return
- for instance, if you you want to return an element that occurs 3 times from an array, then set the "length" to equal 3

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to removing duplicates from an array I usually use one approach:

```
const arrWithDuplicates = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4]
const arrWithUniqueValues = [...new Set(arrWithDuplicates)]

// result will be: [1,2,3,4]
```

This also works with strings and booleans.

Comment: please give more clarity regarding what is `Set`

Comment: "The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references." - MDN Docs.

Comment: So it gives you the possibility to store unique values by default.

Comment: the question is about extracting values which are unique, not removing duplicates of values

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by taking a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and set the value to `false`, if a key has been seen before. Then filter the array by taking the value of the map.

```js
var array = [2, 3, 2],
    result = array.filter(
        Map.prototype.get,
        array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, !m.has(v)), new Map)
    );

console.log(result); // [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just one line

```
arr.filter((item, pos, a) => a.lastIndexOf(item) === a.indexOf(item));
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 5];
const unique = arr.filter((item, pos, a) => a.lastIndexOf(item) === a.indexOf(item));
console.log(unique);
```

#### Util function

```js
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    return this.filter((item, pos, a) => a.lastIndexOf(item) === a.indexOf(item));
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 5].unique());
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the trick below to do the magic

```
if(A.length > 1 && A.length < 100000) {
    const unique_element = [];
    A.map((elem, index, arr) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr.lastIndexOf(elem) === arr.indexOf(elem)) {
                unique_element.push(elem);
            }
        }
    })

    if(unique_element.length > 0) {
        alert(unique_element[0]);
    }
    else {
        alert("No unique value");
    }
}
else {
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUnique = (nums) => {
  let res = 0;
  nums.forEach((element) => {
    res = res ^ element;
  });
  return res;
};
console.log(getUnique([1, 3, 1, 3, 4])); // returns 4
```